# What does str-split function do?

Tags: split, clips

What does (str-split  ) function do in this build 
https://sourceforge.net/p/clipsrules/code/HEAD/tree/branches/63x/core/
P. S. I know what (string-split) function do in other language, like C++, C#, Java, Python. But here, I can not understand. Mr. Riley, all hope for you)))

Comment: There is no such function.

Comment: I have coded one. Where should i send it?

Comment: Just post it here as an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 0):

```
(deffunction MAIN::str-split (?separator ?str)
    (bind $?result (create$))
    (bind ?index 1)
    (while (> (str-length ?str) 0)
        (bind ?index (str-index ?separator ?str))
        (if (neq ?index FALSE) 
            then
                (bind ?temp_string (sub-string 1 (- ?index 1) ?str))
                (if (neq ?temp_string "") 
                    then
                        (bind $?result (insert$ $?result (+ (length$ $?result) 1)
                            (create$ ?temp_string)))
                )
                (bind ?str (sub-string (+ ?index 1) (str-length ?str) ?str))
            else
                (bind $?result (insert$ $?result (+ (length$ $?result) 1) (create$ ?str)))
                (return $?result)
        )
    )
    (return $?result)
)
```